# change attribute value from another class in odoo 8?

Tags: odoo

I have "Item" class :

```
class item(models.Model):
    _name = 'stock.item'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    price = fields.Float(digits=(6, 2))
    quantite = fields.Integer()
```

and  "new_stock_item" class to add new quantite :

```
class new_stock_item(models.Model):
     _name = 'stock.new_stock_item'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    new_quantite = fields.Integer()
    item_id = fields.Many2one('stock.item',ondelete='set null',required=True)
```

I want to update the item quantite values by entering the new value in stock ?
for example:
I have an item : XY with quantity 100 units
if I add a new quantity "new_stock_item" = 50 units
I want to update the "item" quantity for XY to 150 units

Comment: In which table the value should be 150? Please write exact field names, so that I can get better idea. Also write on change of which field, you want the value to be fetched from which table.

Comment: item(Name=XY,Price=2.5,quantite=100), i can now add new_stock_item(1,quantite=50,item(XY)) and new_stock_item(2,quantite=15,item(XY)) ==> I want update item(XY,2.5,165) in the first class (table : item)

Comment: Can you tell me why there is a need of another table 'new_stock_item'?

Comment: to allow traceability and history of previous quantity